# Pagesel does not work

Tags: pagesel

I'm learning how to use `pagesel` correctly. This is my [MWE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t2h6b07b3o1p4ei/2019%201128_question_pagesel.tex?dl=0) for working.

However, a problem occurs when I change options for `pagesel` package.

#### MWE

Line 27: `\usepackage[-]{pagesel}`

1. `\usepackage[-]{pagesel}` => Works! It produces four pages.
2. `\usepackage[1]{pagesel}`, `\usepackage[2]{pagesel}`, `\usepackage[3]{pagesel}` => DOES NOT work. Output files seem to tell me

   > Extra \fi ... \thr@@ \fi \fi

I hate to bother you. But I would be most glad if you kindly give some instruction for this error.

TeXShop version 4.44

MacOS Catalina version 10.15.1

XeLaTeX (typeset)

Comment: So you've given us code which works, but you want to know what is wrong with code you haven't given us which doesn't? Can you see the problem here? We don't want the whole file, but we do need an example of code which produces the error you want help with. Also, please post log output as text rather than an image. You can't search it otherwise and it says nothing to screenreaders.

Comment: Dear @cfr, 
First of all, I would like to express my sincere apology for making the mistake while I posted the question. And thank you very much for instructing me about this matter. I'm trying to make a new MWE for posting.

Comment: Dear @cfr, I just linked the MWE and edited my post. Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: You should have a look to the [documentation of the `pagesel` package](https://ctan.mc2.root.project-creative.net/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/pagesel.pdf), examples are provided at the bottom of page 2. Alternatively, the following (shell, not TeX) command outputs pages n to m of the file file.pdf and stores it in a new file output.pdf: `pdftk file.pdf cat n-m output output.pdf`.

Comment: Dear @jchd, Thank you very much for your help. "even" and "odd" work well. However, \usepackage[1, 2]{pagesel} and so on does not function properly. That's why I am puzzled.

Comment: Thanks for editing. You need to reduce your code to the smallest example you can which reproduces the problem and then post that code here so people can help you. Most people won't follow a dropbox link.

Comment: Dear @cfr, Thank you for your suggestion and encouragement. Then I will try to reduce my code to the smallest example as you instructed.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem with `pagesel`.
To avoid such an issue, I used the package `selectp` instead. For example,

```
\usepackage{selectp}
\outputonly{1-8}
```